# SD card set up using SanDisk Ultra 64GB Card

Tags: sd-card

Transfer files, photo's and videos on to cloud accounts and then delete them from internal storage using my SD card app by
SanDisk that has the option to link my cloud accounts to the app
Will I still have access to my information using the SD card as well as the cloud accounts?